# split string based on number in sql server

Tags: sql-server, string, split, numbers

In sql Server, I need to split a string based on number. What would be the best way for that.
For example, I need to split below string

1. I am looking for this query. 2. Can you please help. 3. I would really appreciate that.

the result I am looking for is

1. I am looking for this answer.
2. Can you please help.
3. I would really appreciate that.

Thanks.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: In the past I have written a C# applications for similar need but I'm not sure if that is an option for you or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but it works. Plenty of room for optimizing if you wish

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @str = '1. I am looking for this query. 2. Can you please help. 3. I would really appreciate that.';

DECLARE @counter INT;
DECLARE @table TABLE ([Text] VARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @currentPattern VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @nextPattern VARCHAR(5);

SET @counter = 1;
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    -- Set the current and next pattern to look for (ex. "1. ", "2. ", etc.)
    SET @currentPattern = '%' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(4)) + '. %';
    SET @nextPattern = '%' + CAST(@counter + 1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + '. %';

    -- Check if the current pattern exists.
    IF (SELECT PATINDEX(@currentPattern, @str)) > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Check if the next pattern exists.
        IF (SELECT PATINDEX(@nextPattern, @str)) > 0
        BEGIN
            -- There is another pattern, so only get the text for the current one.
            INSERT INTO @table VALUES (SUBSTRING(@str, 1, PATINDEX(@nextPattern, @str) - 1));
            SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX(@nextPattern, @str), LEN(@str) - PATINDEX(@nextPattern, @str) + 1);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- No other patterns exist, so just insert the variable text.
            INSERT INTO @table VALUES (@str);
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Current pattern does not exist; break out of loop.
        BREAK;
    END

    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
SELECT * FROM @table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you use Jeff Moden's excellent "CSV Splitter", which can be found at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/.  Jeff has really optimized this kind of operation with some good feedback from the SQL Server community.